Render vs Make. Does "render" imply something negative?
Reading examples of "render" in the sense of "make" in M-W, it occurred to me that "render" is often used in a negative light. For example:

Depression can render a person helpless.
Both passengers were rendered unconscious in the accident.
The sight of her rendered him speechless.
The virus rendered the computer useless.

My assumption:

Render is more formal than Make
Render sth + adj | Make sth + Adj/N
Render sth + [negative adjectives], while Make is neutral.

By this logic, the following sentences are unnatural:

Hey! Get the umbrella! The rain will render you wet. ("render" is overly formal here)
This project would render the chemical an effective medicine. (Suddenly I feel like the adjective "effective" makes this example correct)
The adjective "effective" renders the fifth example correct. ("correct" is positive)

Am I correct?

Regarding the negative connotation, you should check your M-W examples again. The last two sentences had a jury rendering a verdict and a motorist stopping to render aid at an accident. A neutral word that can cover both positive and negative contexts.

In case you were wondering about this point, I would not substitute make for render in any of your four examples. Doing so would render them odd.

I think #5 is odd just because "render X Y" can be expanded to "perform an operation on X that leaves in a state of Y," and this example is more like "add property Y to X." We wouldn't say "The Nobel Prize rendered him a Nobel Prize winner."

Thanks, everbody. @PaulTanenbaum that's something new because I thought in this sense, "make" is a blanket word of "render" since  it can be used in both formal and informal contexts. What's wrong with the first for examples using "make"?

render is generally used in specific contexts: render someone unconscious, render a verdict, render something inoperative or unnecessary, and render fat. I wouldn't use it in a context beyond the standard cases where it's used.

It’s hard to explain why, they just wouldn’t be idiomatic with make. Especially #2. One simply doesn’t say “make someone unconscious.” And make someone speechless also just isn't said. Render someone speechless? Yes. Leave someone speechless? Also yes. But not make.

Yes, render is formal/technical, and
No, it doesn't have to imply negativity. I found render it possible, render it habitable as well as your render it effective.

Thank you. What about render not going with [object + noun]? I read somewhere that we can say "make him the head chef", but not "render him the head chef". Is it always this way?

Yes, I think so. You 'render someone [adjective]' but you don't 'render someone [into] [a noun]'.
